# How to pronounce "$\mapsto$", as in "$x\mapsto f(x)$"?

Tags: functions, terminology, pronunciation

Lots of symbols have their pronunciations. For instance, "$\tbinom {n}{k}$" is pronounced "$n$ choose $k$", and "$\forall$" is pronounced "for all".

> The symbol "$\mapsto$" is used to represent a [mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)), as in
>
> $$x \mapsto f(x)$$
>
> How to pronounce this symbol?

Comment: I think "maps to" is the most common.

Comment: in fact, \$\mapsto\$  maps to $\mapsto$

Comment: I read it “$x$ goes to $f(x)$”

Comment: If you know what it means you can pronounce it with any words that describe it.  I personally use "maps to".  If you are assuming there is verbal shorthand like $\partial x$ is "dee ecks" then... well, I don't think "maps to", at two very short syllables, needs any *verbal* shorthand

Comment: I'm going to argue that $n\choose k$ and $\forall$ are *not* pronounced "$n$ choose $k$" and "for all" but that they are *notation* for "$n$ choose $k$" and "for all".  And $\mapsto$ is notation for "$x$ gets mapped to $f(x)$".  Or if you are short of breath "$x$ goes to $f(x)$" or "$x$ maps to $f(x)$".  Or if you aren't into the whole brevity thing "the value $x$ is mapped by the function $f$ into its image $f(x)$".

Comment: @Lubin, interesting. I always say "goes to" for things like $x_n\to x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no fixed pronunciation - I've heard each of "maps to," "goes to," "is sent to," and further variations.

Keep in mind that there are *lots* of mathematical symbols with no fixed pronunciation: for example, "$\forall$" is pronounced as each of "For all," "For every," "For any," or "For each" with reasonable frequency  (although personally I think the first two are the best choices and I **strongly** object to "For any").

Comment: What's your strong objection to "For any"?

Comment: The word *any* sometimes means *all* and sometimes means *some* and is hence ambiguous.  Sometimes authors try to avoid the ambiguity by italicizing the word, but that doesn’t really help.

Comment: The word “any” is a problem word in English, and should be avoided in mathematical discourse.